# Mestre-Detalhe AngularJS e JSTL

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, jsp

Boa tarde galera.

Seguinte, estou utilizando o AngularJS para adicionar os detalhes de uma venda, porém no lado servidor estou utilizando o Spring MVC com o JSTL fazendo um forEach dos detalhes para adicionar no servidor.

HTML que resgata os detalhes e percorre os elementos:

```
                    <tr id='addr0' items ng-repeat="item in invoice.items">
                            <ec:inputText path="itens[${loop.index}].venda.oid" visible="false" />
                            <ec:inputText path="itens[${loop.index}].oid" visible="false" />
                            <c:forEach items="${venda.itens}" varStatus="loop">
                                <td><ec:inputSelect2 dataUrl="/cadastros/item"
                                        onlyComp="true" dataText="descricao" dataId="oid"
                                        path="itens[${loop.index}].item.oid" /></td>
                                <td><ec:inputText onlyComp="true"
                                        id="venda.itens.quantidade[${loop.index}]" path="itens[${loop.index}].quantidade" /></td>
                                <td><ec:inputDecimal path="itens[${loop.index}].valorUnitario"
                                        onlyComp="true" /></td>
                                <td><ec:inputDecimal path="itens[${loop.index}].valorTotal"
                                        onlyComp="true" /></td>
                                <td><a href class='btn-delete pull-right btn btn-default'
                                    ng:click='removeItem(${loop.index})'><spring:message
                                            code='venda.deletar.item' /></a></td>
                            <tr id='addr${fn:length(venda.itens)}'/>
                        </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
```

HTML utilizando AngularJS que gera os detalhes e atribui o index para o Spring MVC e elementos do HTML:

```
<td><input ng-model='item.descricao' data-url='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cadastros/item' data-id='oid' data-text='descricao' name='teste{{$index}}' id='teste{{$index}}' type='select2' name = 'itens[{{$index}}].produto.oid' style=' min-width: 150px;' class='form-control' /></td><td><input name = 'itens[{{$index}}].quantidade' ng-model='item.quantidade' type='text'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input name = 'itens[{{$index}}].valorUnitario' type='text' ng-model='item.valorUnitario'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input name = 'itens[{{$index}}].valorTotal' value='{{ item.quantidade * item.valorUnitario }}' type='text' readonly  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><a href class='btn-delete pull-right btn btn-default' ng:click='removeItem($index)'><spring:message code='venda.deletar.item' /></a></td>
```

O HTML é construido normalmente, porém quando o usuário clica em salvar as informações da lista, ou melhor, do detalhe, não vão para o servidor, apesar do index estar correto e acredito que esta não seria uma boa prática e gostaria de saber qual a melhor solução que vocês me dariam. De preferência que não precise de AJAX para salvar nem o mestre e nem os detalhes.

Necessariamente tudo que é construido com o AngularJS precisa ser utilizado as ferramentas do AngularJS para serem enviadas ao servidor ou posso deixar que o JSP faça conta do trabalho? Tenho que usar somente uma das ferramentas (JSTL ou AngularJS) para dar conta do trabalho?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Não conheço nada sobre o jstl, então não consigo entender muito bem como as coisas estão funcionando.

Poderia postar o HTML final (client-side)?

Comment: O JSTL está correto? Há um `tr` vazio dentro de outro `tr`. Quanto ao js, algum erro é logado no console?